# What does it mean layout_width/heigth = wrap_content in progress bar and swith

Tags: java, android, user-interface, view, android-wrap-content

i can't understand the value **wrap_content** for View's elements (like *ProgressBar*, *Switch*, primitive *View* with background - that for some reason takes all the available place on screen), it isn't trivial such as *TextView* that *wrap_content* means "be as tall and wide" as the text inside you".
Can anyone help me to understand it?

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/prog_bar_containter"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:elevation="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/rc"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/rc"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/rc"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/rc">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/prog_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: As your comment "I must write some value for layout_width and height, so if i will put a specific number it will be as big as the number (in dp), if i put match_parent it will be as tall and wide as it's parent, but i can't understand the behavior of wrap_content", I think you have thought now what is the meaning of wrap_content for progressbar with my answer. You can test my code for any component you like. Please if you have another question, ask a new one.

Comment: You can check my answer as correct

Comment: If you will read my question you can clearly see that i'm asking for the meaning of wrap_content for components such as : **ProgressBar** and **Switch**. In your official answer you are explaining how to (check) the size of the components and it isn't related to my question. In comments you explains that wrap_content means "take" component default size, and this should be the answer so i can approve it. I appreciate you help very very very much, but in order to approve you answer you should write in the answer what you told me in your latest comments.

Comment: Answer is edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find how much is width and height of an component which is used in the layout, you can use this code. Here height and width of a progressbar is set to wrap_content, it means that its width and height have default sizes, and we want to know how much is these default sizes. Result is in `px`.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        progressbar.post(Runnable {
            val a= progressbar.getWidth()
            val b=progressbar.getHeight()
            Log.d("abc", a.toString())
            Log.d("abc", b.toString())
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: @MohamadMoeinGolchin, Hi. thanks for the answer, but you didn't refer to *progressBar* and *switch* at all. As i said in the question, i understand wrap_content meaning in *TextView*,*Button*,ImageView, layouts, etc. **But** what is the meaning of it in components like  **ProgressBar** and **Switch**?

Comment: For them wrap_content and match_parent are the same apparently, but when you want to set gravity for them it is different that their width is wrap_content or match_parent. @Eitanos30

Comment: No, it's not. I just checked it. match_parent takes all available space in it's parent layout, and wrap_content only taking a small place

Comment: Yes, as I said when you want to set gravity for them, it's important to be wrap_content or match_parent. But apparently they are the same. @Eitanos30

Comment: Did you check it? Because i just checked and they look different. wrap_content is small while match_parent making the  progress bar to be as big as the container he "lives" in

Comment: Attach your result images in your question please @Eitanos30

Comment: How can i attach it? it isn't part of my question so it isn't seem right to attach image as part of my question. Is there a different way to attach it?

Comment: Come to chat please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211658/discussion-between-mohammadmoeingolchin-and-eitanos30).

Comment: I will join but i think the issue can serve a lot of developers. Cause it seems that people  can find the answer for it

Comment: Still can't understand the meaning of wrap_content in **ProgressBar** and **Switch** compontnets

Comment: In your code that you have attached, you think what should be instead of wrap_content? @Eitanos30

Comment: I must write some value for layout_width and height, so if i will put a specific number it will be as big as the number (in dp), if i put match_parent it will be as tall and wide as it's parent, but i can't understand the behavior of wrap_content

Comment: My answer is edited and I think it is what you want @Eitanos30

Comment: Thanks mate, but i only want to understand the meaning of wrap_content value for layout_width and layout_height in component that doesn't have content like TextView and Button, and i still can't understand it

Comment: As I said you, they have default size and with my code you can find their size. @Eitanos30

Comment: So, do you say, that wrap_content means taking default size of the *ProgressBar*, *Switch*?

Comment: Yes, as I said you last night and today @Eitanos30

Comment: I think you should say in your answer that wrap_content mean a default *ProgressBar* size, cause my question is talking purely on the meaning of it and not on how to calculate it, and i will approve this answer (hopefully you are right in you answer). Thanks a lot

Comment: I said you default size several times @Eitanos30

Answer (score 0):

In each view component you find method `onMeasure` here developer calculate measure Size of
view which make view appear will
if you specific height width you make the view appear like that if you add custom height of width may view don't appear well  (Sorry for my english )

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer, but i didn't understand how it's related to wrap_content value for width and height?

Comment: simply developer calculate better width and height  
fill_parent is deprecated now use match_parent
this use to make view in all parent if parent is match_parent it will match screen